# Why print function is not printing when invoked with java -jar?

Tags: java, jar, clojure, leiningen

I'm learning **clojure** with **leiningen**. I have written a simple code to test ***lein*** & ***java -jar*** commands. Here is my **project.clj** file:

```
$ cat project.clj 
(defproject hello "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "FIXME: write description"
  :url "http://example.com/FIXME"
  :license {:name "Eclipse Public License"
            :url "http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html"}
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.8.0"]]
  :main ^:skip-aot hello.core
  :target-path "target/%s"
  :profiles {:uberjar {:aot :all}})
```

Here is my source code:

```
$ cat src/hello/core.clj 
(ns hello.core
  (:gen-class))

(defn -main
  [& args]
  (print "Hello, World!"))
```

When I run this code with ***lein***, It work fine. It's shown here

```
$ lein run
Hello, World!$
```

When I tried to run **java -jar**, It didn't work

```
$ lein uberjar
Compiling hello.core
Created /home/rishi/hello/target/uberjar/hello-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
Created /home/rishi/hello/target/uberjar/hello-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT-standalone.jar

$ java -jar target/uberjar/hello-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT-standalone.jar
```

I didn't understand, why I didn't get required output with **java -jar**?

If I replace **print** with **println** in source file, I got required output with both **lein run** & **java -jar**.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your process output is buffered. `print` does not flush the output. Most of the time your output stream will be set up to automatically flush on newlines, which is why the `println` displays. If you need to flush without a newline, you can call the `(flush)` function.

Comment: Cool! I understood. I got my answer. Thanks. @noisesmith

Comment: Me to!  #(me-to!)